# What is the "single equation" in string theory that's an inch long?

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, string-field-theory

Michio Kaku, famous theoretical physicist claims to be one of the founders of string field theory and to have contributed a equation that's "no bigger than your thumb" that ties general relativity and quantum field theory together. What is this equation I keep hearing about and why is it important?

Comment: In all fairness, it's cheating. For instance, in GR, use of the metric is used often. This essentially lets you compress the spacetime of a system into a single "matrix" equation. Of course, it really is still *one* equation, it just keeps a lot of things behind the curtain.

Comment: I'm assuming it's an equation ala $E = mc^2$ but I cannot find it on the Internet.

Comment: One shouldn't take everything seriously that Michio Kaku says. This is certainly one of these things that I would just ignore because it's completely meaningless. Even Newtonian mechanics requires a small (roughly 150 page) textbook to develop the core ideas of the theory and it gets exponentially more elaborate from there.